# Clearing RSL in Cache

Tags: apache-flex, caching

I have built a flex application which has a "main" project and it is assosciated with a few RSL's which are loaded and cached once i run my "main" application. The problem i am facing is that the newer versions of my RSL's are not being loaded as the cache holds the older version of my RSL and execxutes the same. Each time i have got to clear the cache to execute the new version of my RSL's, which is irritating. So, can anyone suggest me a solution to get the newly updated RSL's loaded and working..

Thanks,
BJ

Comment: take a look at [this blog post](http://www.kalengibbons.com/blog/index.php/2008/11/clearing-framework-rsls-from-your-flash-player-cache/). Hopefully it will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

That blog post has the answer - you need to clear your flash player cache in the flash player settings dialog.